# MVC3 Embed Models within Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am encountering many problems (validation, serialisation) when using models that embed other models and just wanted to know whether anybody has received issue with this kind of thing before. For example I have an enquiry form which has the following model attached:

**Model**

```
namespace
{
    public class EnquiryStudent
    {
        public enquiry enquiry { get; set; }
        public student student { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

The enquiry and student models (embedded inside enquiry student) are auto generated from the database (I am using database first approach).

Now for example a problem I get here is that I use a view to display a form based on the above model:

**View**

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Enquiry</legend>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.student.firstname)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.student.firstname)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.student.firstname)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.student.surname)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.student.surname)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.student.surname)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.student.email)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.student.email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.student.email)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.enquiry.subject)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.enquiry.subject)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.enquiry.subject)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.enquiry.enquiry_text)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.enquiry.enquiry_text)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.enquiry.enquiry_text)
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" class="rounded-button-gray-shades" value="Send" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

and the client side validation works great for everything except the enquiry text (an attribute of the embedded enquiry within EnquiryStudent model, i.e. it doesn't validate this client side only server side??

Now even stranger if I either change the enquiry_text to be a TextBoxFor instead of TextAreaFor it works great.
Or if I make a text area for another entity by adding a dummy field to the EnquiryStudent model (not embedded in another model) it works fine.

Can somebody please shed some light as like I said this is not the only quirk that I have been having with this kind of model relationship.

Thanks,

Comment: Is it the _ in the enquiry_text? I have noticed MVC swapping . into _ in the produced form.

Comment: Hi Rob, nice idea, unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem though. Any other ideas? Cheers

Comment: Have you had a look at the js it produces?